# Keep text floated to the right while image on the left

Tags: html, css

I want the image to be in the left and the text to be on the right. problem is the text goes under the image when having a lot of text. 
How can I keep the text to the right without targeting each text element, because I have blog posts and some divs will have spans, others will have p tags and so on... Is there a way to specify that the image will have no text under it by targeting that image only?
Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/7hf49j6g/4/

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/75x57/c2a7c2/fff.jpg">
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</p>
    <span>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</span>
    <a href="#">commodo ligula eget dolor</a>
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mussdfsdf 
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:25px;
}
```

Comment: You should have a general idea of how much text you should expect to appear, so just declare a `margin-bottom` property to the `img` in question and adjust the value accordingly, the idea here is to have a large enough bottom margin to keep the text from wrapping below the image.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow: hidden` to the `<p>` tags should do the trick:

```css
img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:25px;
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img-section col-md-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/75x57/c2a7c2/fff.jpg">
     </a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-section col-md-8">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculasdipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculasdipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculasdipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculasdfadfasdfus mus</p>
    <span>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</span>
    <a href="#">commodo ligula eget dolor</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the other tags are under the image like span and a tags.. also I just added a text with no tag and that appears as well. I need the image to have no text under it no matter what tags there. thanks.

Comment: In that case perhaps you're better using a grid structure like Bootstrap? I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending just on the image size. Just use this:

```
img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:25px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the HTML (the raw text, span & link should be in the same paragraph) and then use flexbox.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/75x57/c2a7c2/fff.jpg">
  </a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa strong. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
    mus
    <span>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes</span>
    <a href="#">commodo ligula eget dolor</a> parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mussdfsdf</p>
</div>
```